# ISBN-10: order of weights does not matter - why?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Quoting Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISBN#ISBN-10_check_digits):

> [The check digit] and must be such that the sum of the ten digits,
> each multiplied by its (integer) weight, **descending** from 10 to 1,
> is a multiple of 11.
>
> [...]
>
> It is also true for ISBN-10s that the sum of all ten digits, each
> multiplied by its weight in **ascending** order from 1 to 10, is a
> multiple of 11.

I fail to see how this is possible. Can someone explain why this is the case?

Test case: 3446189009

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are using modular arithmetic here.  If you have not seen and practiced modular arithmetic before, stop reading this and go learn the basics first.

For starters, notice that $11$ is prime.  Now... let your digits be named $a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots,a_{10}$.  Given specific values of $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_9$ you should be able to see that there is exactly one value of $a_{10}$ such that $10a_1+9a_2+8a_3+\dots+2a_9+a_{10}\equiv 0\pmod{11}$ and clearly there will always be such a value.  To see this, simply subtract everything except the $a_{10}$ to the other side and perform the necessary arithmetic.  For your example, imagine we didn't know the last number... Well, we can use the first nine numbers to find it.  It would be

$$a_{10}\equiv-10\cdot 3 -9\cdot 4-8\cdot 4 - 7\cdot 6-6\cdot 1-5\cdot 8-4\cdot 9-3\cdot 0 - 2\cdot 0\\\equiv -222\equiv -222+220+11\equiv 9\pmod{11}$$

Indeed, our last digit was nine, as expected.  Whatever our first nine digits were, we can always define our tenth digit based on those previous nine such that it will work.

In fact, given any nine digits, not necessarily the first nine... we could do the same thing.  Suppose that it was the $k$'th digit that we did not know and we knew the other nine digits.  Again, subtract everything but the $k$'th digit and its coefficient to the other side to get $(11-k)a_k\equiv \underbrace{-10a_1-9a_2-\dots-a_{10}}_{\text{missing k'th term}}$.  Now, since $11$ is prime, we know we can find $(11-k)^{-1}$, whatever that happened to be, and then can find $a_k$ as $(11-k)^{-1}(\underbrace{-10a_1-9a_2-\dots-a_{10}}_{\text{missing k'th term}})$

Now... as for why we have that we could have used weights in increasing order *or* in decreasing order... given that the weights give the expected results in increasing order recognize that $11a_1+11a_2+11a_3+\dots+11a_{10}$ is clearly a multiple of $11$.  Since we know that $10a_1+9a_2+8a_3+\dots+1a_{10}$ is also a multiple of $11$ by hypothesis, we could subtract the one from the other.  Since a multiple of $11$ minus another multiple of $11$ is again clearly going to be a multiple of $11$... we have $(11a_1+11a_2+\dots+11a_{10})-(10a_1+9a_2+\dots+1a_{10}) = 1a_1+2a_2+3a_3+\dots+10a_{10}$ is going to be a multiple of $11$ as we desired to prove.